# It's possible to create an async function in Node.js that runs in parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, parallel-processing

My goal is to run the `longRunnigTask` and the `quickTask` functions in parallel:

```
function longRunnigTask() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log('longRunnigTask started');
        for (let i = 0; i < 999999999; i++) {};
        console.log('longRunnigTask ended');
        resolve();
    });
}
function quickTask() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log('quickTask started');
        console.log('quickTask ended');
        resolve();
    });
}


(function() {
    Promise.all([
        longRunnigTask(),
        quickTask()
        ]);
})();
```

My expected output is:

```
longRunnigTask started
quickTask started
quickTask ended
longRunnigTask ended
```

But I get:

```
longRunnigTask started
longRunnigTask ended
quickTask started
quickTask ended
```

It's possible to achieve this without external libraries or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Are these functions CPU-bound or IO-bound? If they're CPU-bound as in the example, use a web worker, if IO bound then they'll run in parallel.

Comment: No external library is required. See [works_threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) - "The worker_threads module enables the use of threads that execute JavaScript in parallel.". This module as been available since Node 10.5 - https://blog.logrocket.com/node-js-multithreading-what-are-worker-threads-and-why-do-they-matter-48ab102f8b10/ (discusses what/why). The API can be wrapped into Promises, as shown in the first link. This is not the only 'parallel' module that ships with Node.

Comment: If you're not doing anything asyncronous in these functions, they will not run in parallel. You probably need to take a look at web workers.

Comment: Or, `worker_threads` (see above) or `child_process` - both of which are standard - or..

Comment: So with only `Promises` it's not possibile to achieve parallelism right?

Comment: With `Promises` _alone_, "code" parallelism is not possible (as they are really just a set of guidelines over callbacks). However, `Promises` can _wrap_ parallelism of multiple execution contexts (eg. as supported via `worker_threads`) and marshal back to the original context. Consider that Promises wrapping I/O operation are themselves a _form of parallelism_, albeit over the I/O operation (and *not* the execution context).

Comment: Great explanation, thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

In your main long block loop you can do some super tiny pauses like this

```js
const timeout = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

function longRunnigTask() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        console.log('longRunnigTask started');
        for (let i = 0; i < 999999999; i++) {
          if(i === 5555) await timeout(1);
        };
        
        console.log('longRunnigTask ended');
        resolve('res from long');
    });
}
function quickTask() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log('quickTask started');
        console.log('quickTask ended');
        resolve('res from quick');
    });
}


(async () => {
  longRunnigTask().then((res) => console.log(res));
  quickTask().then((res) => console.log(res));
})();
```

Comment: @user2864740 check my updated answer. Of course you need to modify logic in your main long running block

Comment: @Couper try it now. Of course worker_threads is cool option, but it's also achievable this way